# send php form via XML and save the response as a cookie

Tags: php, xml, forms

I want to use a php form that has 2 fields:

email / password and send it to a 3rd party site via XML, it will then return an XML response that I want to capture The Name and echo in another place on the header (I was thinking about saving it as a cookie but I am not sure the best way).
Below is the code I was trying but I cannot tell if it is working since I am not capturing the response.

```
echo'<form name="ppost" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">

<input type="text" name="emailaddress" />
<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="submit" name="SUbmit" value="Submit" />

</form>';


extract($_POST);

 $n = "\n\n";
 $inputdata = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?'.'>'.$n.'
<CustomerCredential  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EmailAddress>'.$emailaddress.'</EmailAddress>
<Password>'.$password.'</Password>

</CustomerCredential>';


$x = curl_init("https:AnotherWebsite.com/CustomerSession");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputdata);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($x);
curl_close($x);
echo $data;
```

Comment: nice XSS hole... hopefully no one's password has a `>` in it...

Comment: @roje0931: Always validate and sanitize user input. http://xkcd.com/327/